# Display PDF in browser when Content-Disposition is set to attachment

Tags: javascript, http, pdf, browser, content-disposition

I need to display PDF in browser. The URL of pdf that I'm displaying comes from a server that I do not own. In the response header that service sets 'Content-Disposition' header as 'attachment' and because of that when I open that URL in browsr window it immediately starts downloading instead of displaying.

I want to show this PDF in the browser instead of downloading it but this 'Content-Disposition' header is not letting me do that. Is there any way I can download the contents of PDF and then show it in browser? or use some kind of library to do that?

I tried using pdfobject.com but it is having issues with displaying this URL as well. ( I tried changing the code to display PDF where content-disposition header was not set and that worked)

Comment: you can fetch the pdf via binary ajax, then use window.URL.createObjectURL(blobResponse) to turn the doc into a new url which you can show in an iframe or send to window.open()

Comment: what is binary ajax? can you write an exaple?

Comment: also it looks like blob object is not supported in IE9

Comment: there are ugly ways of doing binary ajax with ie8+9. but if you need to support them, i would think a php re-proxy that omits the content-disposition header would be your best bet.